# Blender 2.79b (and RC 2.80) require opengl32.dll be present before Blender will open (Windows 10)

Tags: error

Blender 2.79b and 2.80 does not load unless I place the opengl32.dll file in the Blender directory. I've gone through all of the drivers I know to update but still no luck. Even placing the opengl32.dll file in the directory does not allow me to load previous .blend files.

Windows 10 Home
V 10.0.18362
i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2208 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Update on 7/19.
Went to Nvidia website (thank you) and downloaded the latest driver. Ran the blender_debug_gpu cmd from 2.80 with exactly the same result. The results:

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.80 (sub 74)
Build: Thu 07/11/2019 09:59 AM Windows 
argv[0] = blender
argv[1] = --debug
argv[2] = --python-expr
argv[3] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
read file 
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
Error   : Unrecognized Exception
Address : 0x00007FFC3FC7A839
Module  : C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

This is a new computer so I'm almost to the point of returning it if I can get this figured out. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: are you trying to use a 32bit build? Try a 64bit one.

Comment: Using 64-bit build Tried 32-bit with same result.

Comment: Copying/Moving .dlls around is very, *very* wrong. When you say it doesn't run, are there any errors displayed? In the install directory of 2.8 you should find `blender_debug_log.cmd`. Please run this to create a debug log and add the results to your question.

Comment: @rjg *"Copying/Moving .dlls around is very, very wrong"* pasting opengl32 dll file into Blender directory is not wrong, it is recommended way to diagnose if problems are caused by graphic card (or its absence / unavailability).

Comment: @MrZak My bad, yes the *softwaregl* test using (https://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/) is valid. I thought he has moved it there from somewhere else on the system. Looks like OpenGL can't be found or not in a suitable version. I'd take the following steps to see what's wrong 1) In case you haven't already updated the driver of your graphics card, update it https://www.nvidia.de/Download/index.aspx?lang=en  2) If that doesn't work start Blender using `blender_debug_gpu.cmd` and look for errors regarding OpenGL (post updates) 3) Repeat the previous step but with the softwaregl.

Comment: Updated the entry. No change with updated graphics driver and running the blender_debug_gpu.cmd. Exact same text output.

Comment: @Tom is your graphics card working/detected by the OS? Please run `dxdiag.exe` (either by opening a command prompt or searching for it the start menu) and check the display tab. Does it display your GPU and/or any errors?

Comment: Really appreciate the help @rjg. I figured out the problem. After running dxdiag it did not show any reference to my Nvidia graphics card. A couple of USB devices but that's it. Then it dawned on me that I am using a USB docking station so I can have multiple screens. For whatever reason, it wasn't accessing the graphics card. Once I unpugged the docking station I was able to start up Blender without any problem. I have used  the docking station successfully in the past with other laptops so I'll have to sort through how to fix that. But Blender is working A-Ok! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Tom You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: And for future reference - the issue appears to be a Windows 10 bug. I had to Disable the onboard Intel graphics card to force Windows to use the NVidia card. This solved the problem:  https://support.plugable.com/t/ud-3900-and-nvidia-geforce-920mx-with-hdmi-connection/11183

Comment: @Tom You can post this as an answer to your own question. It makes it easier to find for others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is how I solved it.

The PC has two graphics cards: one built-in Intel and one NVIDIA. By default, Windows (10-pro) recognizes and enables both. However, Blender default will work only with one of them. If you happen to use the other one instead, then Blender will close on start up.

Solution: Disable the graphics card which you are not using. Blender will go with the other one. It should work.

(Actually my experience is with Blender 2.90.1. Blender closes/crashes on loading/start up)